# Mirrior DB cannot be recovered after switching off the partner off on the primary

Tags: sql-server

Primary db (ldf) log is huge transaction is getting killed/rolled back.
we want to drop the mirroring  and recover the mirrored db.
we set the partner off both on primary n secondary. db could not recovered saying 
mirrorin still there.

how to solve this.

Comment: What is the status of the secondary db?

Comment: What are the results of `SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases`?